# Webscraper Python Xpath IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, web-scraping, xpath

I need to scrape this webpage: https://br.advfn.com/bolsa-de-valores/bovespa/aper3/balanco

My Selenium code crashes most times and I noticed that the data I need is not loaded with scripts, so I don't need to use Selenium for this specific webpage and I tried this:

```
def minerar_advfns(ticker):
    quote = 'https://br.advfn.com/bolsa-de-valores/bovespa/' + ticker + '/balanco'
    page = requests.get(quote)
    time.sleep(0.9)
    dom = etree.HTML(page.content)
    f = open('www.htm', 'w')
    temp1 = str(page.content)
    f.write(temp1)
    f.close()
    lucro = dom.xpath('//*[@id="financials_table_2"]/table/tbody/tr[11]/td[2]/text()')[0]    
    print(lucro)
```

I'm trying to scrape the data point '1.605' with this code. It stops in the penultimate line and says 'IndexError: list index out of range'.

When I check the 'www.htm' webpage saved, that '1.605' value is there exactly where my xpath points to. I tried with and without '/text()' and '[0]'. If I remove the [0] it prints '[]'

Answer (score 0):

Xpath has tbody tag problem

You can change //*[@id="financials_table_2"]/table/tbody/tr[11]/td[2]/text()

to   //*[@id="financials_table_2"]/table//tr[11]/td[2]/text()